# phpmailer SMTP error

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am using this php code to send email through gmail account . but its showing smtp error .
I have googled it . but not found any specific answer . would anyone please help to find the solution ??

I have hosted this code in my webserver

error :
"SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message was not sent
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."

code:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$email = $_POST['email_address'];

$username = 'username@gmail.com';  //your gmail address
$password = 'password';  //password


send_mail_to_subscriber();


function send_mail_to_subscriber()
{

    global $username,$password,$email;
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $mailer->IsSMTP();
    $mailer->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465';
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

    $mailer->Username = $username;  
    $mailer->Password = $password;  
    $mailer->From = $username;  
    $mailer->FromName = $username; 

    $mailer->Body = 'this is a message';
    $mailer->Subject = 'this is a subject';
    $mailer->AddAddress($email);  
    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
       echo "Message was not sent<br/ >";
       echo "Mailer Error: " . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Download link has been sent to your email address";
    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your Host and add the following:

```
$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mailer->Port = 465;
```

Comment: Is your TCP out open for 465?

Comment: I am not sure actually . Is there any way to check ??

Comment: I'd ask your server administrator/hosting company.

Comment: Sparrow, Postbox, and other clients are currently having send issues, showing the following error: "Unexpected error (8/451/4.3.0 Mail server temporarily rejected message. bx19sm8004630vdb.2)." So this could easily be what you're seeing. (Tested on Gmail account and Google Apps for Business account). In theory this should be temporary.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;     // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->Mailer       = "smtp";
    $mail->setCharset   = "UTF-8";
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug    = 0;      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host         = 'smtp.gmail.com'; //Specify main and backup SMTPservers
    $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;         // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username     = 'gmail user name';     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password     = 'gmail password';                 // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure   = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port         = 'Your Outgoing server port number';// TCP port to connect to
    $mail->From         = 'from address ';
    $mail->FromName     = ' from name';
```

To Identify the Issues, Change the value  $mail->SMTPDebug = 1,2.3.4.