# phpmailer not sending email

Tags: php

i am using phpmailer and i am getting following error:

Message was not sent
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->IsSMTP();
$mailer->Host = 'ssl://smtp.myhost.com:465';
$mailer->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mailer->Username = 'myemail@myhost.com';
$mailer->Password = 'mypass';
$mailer->From = 'myemailagain@myhost.com';
$mailer->FromName = 'myname';
$email1 = $_GET['email'];
$verification = rand();
$mailer->Body = 'Welcome to our site';
$mailer->Subject = 'verification';
$mailer->AddAddress($email1);
if(!$mailer->Send())
{
   echo "Message was not sent<br/ >";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
   echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

note: i use "myhost.com" but it's not my real domain

Comment: You need to actually point it at an SMTP host. `myhost.com` doesn't exist.

Comment: Does your SMTP server actually support ssl email on port 465?

Comment: yes it should, is there any command I can check to verify this? (I have a default install http/https, email, ftp, ftps, pop, imap server - dedicated hosted brand new)

Comment: @Crontab I cannot connect, i guess that is the problem now

Comment: This question has been asked and answered a number of times. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957573

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are specifying your host incorrectly.  Try this instead:

```
$mailer->Host="smtp.myhost.com";
$mailer->Port=465;
$mailer->SMTPSecure="ssl"; //If this doesn't work, try 'tls'
```

If it still doesn't work, consider setting:

```
$mailer->SMTPDebug=1;
```

Also, make sure PHP's OpenSSL extension is enabled.

Comment: 1. the service wasnt working and now its up. 2. my original code wasnt working but this one does thanks